# Proving $\lbrace x: f(x) \not =g(x) \rbrace$ is Lebesgue Measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Prove: $$\lbrace x: f(x) \neq g(x)\rbrace$$ is Lebesgue measurable if $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions on the reals.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way: $f(x) \ne g(x)$ iff there is a rational number $r$ such that either $f(x) < r < g(x)$ or $f(x) > r > g(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that for a measurable function $F$, the set $\{x: F(x)=0\}$ is measurable.  Then apply this to the function $f-g$, and take a compliment.

Comment: +1. Yet another way: $f(x)- g(x) \not = 0$ if and only if there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $f(x) - g(x) > 1/n$.

Comment: Of course this requires proving that $f - g$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: True, I assumed that would have been shown already (typical "day 1 of measurable functions" proof).